# Looking for an abstraction that allows a class to spawn actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have a class that offers different kinds of `Source`s to it's clients. When a `Source` is run, an actor should be spawned that feeds new entries into the respective stream. So my class needs to be able to spawn actors. I know of two ways to do this: Using the `ActorContext` of another actor or using the `ActorSystem`. Is there a common abstraction for the ability to spawn new actors so I could inject a helper into my class that just allows it to spawn actors if required regardless of how it is done?

I created an `ActorSpawner` interface for this purpose and it worked pretty well so far:

```
trait ActorSpawner {

  def spawn[T](behavior: Behavior[T]): ActorRef[T]

  def spawn[T](behavior: Behavior[T], name: String): ActorRef[T]

}
```

However, since I upgraded to Akka 2.6 I frequently get these error messages:

*ERROR akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy - Unsupported access to ActorContext from the outside
of Actor[akka://...]. No message is currently processed by the actor, but ActorContext was called from Thread[...]*

It seems this wasn't a problem before the upgrade but now I'm wondering whether what I was doing was advisable anyway or if this is kind of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typed, with the exception of the guardian actor (the one created when creating the `ActorSystem`), actors can only be spawned by other actors.

There are still plenty of cases where code executing outside of an actor wants to spawn an actor.  For this, you can send a message to an actor and have that actor spawn an actor with the desired behavior.

If you have an actor whose sole purpose is spawning other actors, Akka includes the [`SpawnProtocol`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/SpawnProtocol$.html), which is compatible with the ask pattern:

```
trait ActorSpawner {
  def spawn[T](behavior: Behavior[T], name: String): Future[ActorRef[T]]

  def spawn[T](behavior: Behavior[T]): Future[ActorRef[T]] = spawn(behavior, "")
}

def spawnerFor(spawningActor: ActorRef[SpawnProtocol.Spawn])(implicit system: ActorSystem[Nothing]): ActorSpawner = {
  import system.executionContext
  import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10.seconds)  // or whatever, can also make this an arg

  new ActorSpawner {
    def spawn[T](behavior: Behavior[T], name: String): Future[ActorRef[T]] =
      spawningActor.ask(SpawnProtocol.Spawn(behavior, name, Props.empty, _))
  }
}
```

If your guardian actor happens to only spawn other actors on demand, it can implement `SpawnProtocol`, in which case the `ActorSystem` is itself an `ActorRef[SpawnProtocol.Spawn]`, so that could be further simplified to

```
def spawnerFor(system: ActorSystem[SpawnProtocol.Spawn]): ActorSpawner = {
  import system.executionContext
  import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10.seconds)
  implicit val scheduler = system.scheduler

  new ActorSpawner {
    def spawn[T](behavior: Behavior[T], name: String): Future[ActorRef[T]] =
      system.ask(SpawnProtocol.Spawn(behavior, name, Props.empty, _))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know of two ways to do this: Using the ActorContext of another actor or using the ActorSystem

I think this is true for the **Classic** (i.e. untyped) Actor API and the common abstraction is `akka.actor.ActorRefFactory` which both `akka.actor.ActorSystem` and `akka.actor.ActorContext` extend. This is where `def actorOf(props: Props): ActorRef` lives for creating new actors.

In the new typed Actor API this is no longer the case. You can't create an actor from `akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem`, you can only create it from `akka.actor.typed.scaladsl/javadsl.ActorContext` with `spawn*` family of methods with the exception of the guardian/root actor of given actor system, which you can create by `ActorSystem(guardianBehavior: Behavior[T], name: String)` and friends in Scala or with `ActorSystem.create(...)` equivalent in Java.

The `ActorContext` should only be accessed from a message processing thread of the actor that owes it or from `setup` method and the runtime check that produces the error log is in place since `2.6.6`. You probably call the object from somewhere else. Perhaps this post will be useful in tracking where exactly: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/akka-2-6-6-context-log-error-string-failed/6708/2

Comment: Ok, so the abstraction I'm looking for doesn't exist anymore. Is it ok to define it myself even if the only implementation that is used creates actors via the guardian actor? Or is this some kind of anti-pattern and I actually shouldn't need it?

Comment: It's hard to answer that question without looking at the code. I wouldn't hastily call this an "antipattern". I would ask, what's the purpose of introducing that abstraction. Is there any benefit like hiding complexity, making the code easier to understand, use, etc. Perhaps making the code work for both classic actor and typed actor system would be a good reason to have such abstraction if that's what you're trying to achieve.   If not then you can argue that this abstraction is serving no purpose and therefore not needed... so this would be my way of saying "it depends"